# i keep on getting this error:Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.How to resolve it?

Tags: python, flask, backend

I tried the previous solutions that were mentioned for the same error issue but none of them works for me.

this is what appears on the command prompt:

```
(env) C:\Users\Desktop\flask>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployme
nt.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-05-22 00:58:14,437] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 24
47, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 19
52, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 18
21, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", lin
e 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 19
50, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 19
36, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\flask\app.py", line 9, in index
    return render_template('index.html')
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py",
line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py"
, line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py"
, line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py"
, line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", li
ne 127, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py"
, line 638, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py"
, line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "c:\users\desktop\flask\env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", li
ne 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Udai\Desktop\flask\templates\index.html", line 1, in template
    <!--{%extends 'base.html%'}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}'
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2020 00:58:14] "←[35m←[1mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
```

When I ran the debugger it showed me this:
]
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Traceback (most recent call last)

I tried 
app = Flask(**name**, template_folder='../templates')and
app = Flask(**name**, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')and 
this app=Flask(**name**,template_folder='template')

but none works for me.

how do I resolve the above problem?

Comment: this is a guess since we dont have your code (please put your code in!) but if you look at the error at the bottom: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}'` Seems like you have an extra `}` somewhere. Try checking your code for it.

Comment: you are not closing your comment `<!--{%extends 'base.html%'} -->`